# cout produces weird output

Tags: c++, iostream, cout

This is my code:

```
void Sublist<T>::showSublist() const {
    for (int i = 0; i < indicies.size(); i++) {
        iTunesEntry& entry = (*originalObjects)[indicies[i]];
        cout << "sublist[" << i << "] = ";
        cout << entry.getArtist() << " " << entry.getArtistLastName() << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

This is what I expect to see when I run this code:

```
 sublist[0] = Foo Fighters
 sublist[1] = Eric Clapton
 sublist[2] = Howlin' Wolf
 sublist[3] = Janiva Magness
```

However, this is what I get:

```
 Fighters] = Foo Fighters
 Clapton1] = Eric Clapton
 Wolfst[2] = Howlin' Wolf
 Magness3] = Janiva Magness
```

Does anyone have any possible explanation for why this might be or what I can look for in my code to find a solution?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have an error in your code that parses data into `iTunesEntry`.  There are extra control characters (most likely carriage return `\r`) in the text that you are not handling.  Most probably, you're dealing with a text file created in Windows, and have either hand-rolled your parsing code to search for only `\n`, or you're running this on a non-Windows system.

Comment: In addition to above comment, you can add a newline `\n` here in your `cout` statement i.e. `cout << "sublist[" << i << "] = \n";` and then observe the behavior of the printed output. Most probably, there's a loose `\r` that is not being handled correctly as pointed out in the comment above.